# Widget not appearing in customizer

Tags: widgets, theme-customizer

Hello I have a theme installed but on the homepage the homepage content widget section does not appear in the customizer view. I have it set on the wp-admin themes settings but when I go to the customizer it does not show all of the widgets that are setup in the admin settings. Every page I go to in the customizer only shows 5 widgets (not sure if theres a setting to enable more than 5) but I cant seem to get this figured out. any help is greatly appreciated .. I have 2 screenshots with this post to show whats going on[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmA3y.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Widget Areas

It is clear from the above screenshots that the theme does not have support for widgets on all the pages **equally**.

It can be said that, one page supports 4 widget areas and the other page support 6 widget areas.

You may also try visiting **theme options** for this, because there might be some setting about adding widget areas for particular theme page.

Or you may list your **theme name** if available on wordpress.org  for further assistance.